# Custom Control Button C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I need some help with a custom control. I create a IconButton ton bind some symbol et i try to make something like a switch button but with symbol this is my class.

```
public sealed partial class IconButton : UserControl
    { 
        private SolidColorBrush _symbolColor;
        public SolidColorBrush SymbolColor
        {
            get { return _symbolColor; }
            set
            {
                SI.Foreground = value;
                _symbolColor = value;
            }
        }

        public Ways _way;
        public Ways Way
        {
            get { return _way; }
            set { _way = value; }
        }

        private bool _autoChangeColor = false;
        public bool AutoChangeColor
        {
            get { return _autoChangeColor; }
            set { _autoChangeColor = value; }
        }

        private bool _cursor = false;
        public bool Cursor
        {
            get { return _cursor; }
            set
            {
                if(value)
                {
                    BT.Click += Click;
                }
                _cursor = value;
            }
        }

        private bool _reverse = false;
        public bool Reverse
        {
            get { return _reverse; }
            set
            {
                _reverse = value;
            }
        }
        public void Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeCursor();
        }
        private void InitCursor()
        {
            if (!Reverse)
            {
                if (Symbol == Symbol.Forward)
                {
                    Way = Ways.Left;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.Back)
                {
                    Way = Ways.Right;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.Accept)
                {
                    if (AutoChangeColor)
                    {
                        SI.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    }
                    Way = Ways.Cancel;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.Cancel)
                {
                    if (AutoChangeColor)
                    {
                        SI.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    }
                    Way = Ways.Accept;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.FullScreen)
                {
                    Way = Ways.BackToWindow;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.BackToWindow)
                {
                    Way = Ways.FullScreen;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Symbol == Symbol.Forward)
                {
                    Way = Ways.Right;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.Back)
                {
                    Way = Ways.Left;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.Accept)
                {
                    if (AutoChangeColor)
                    {
                        SI.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    }
                    Way = Ways.Accept;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.Cancel)
                {
                    if (AutoChangeColor)
                    {
                        SI.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    }
                    Way = Ways.Cancel;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.FullScreen)
                {
                    Way = Ways.FullScreen;
                }
                else if (Symbol == Symbol.BackToWindow)
                {
                    Way = Ways.BackToWindow;
                }
            }
        }
        private void ChangeCursor()
        {
            if(Cursor)
            {
                if (!Reverse)
                {
                    if (Symbol == Symbol.Forward)
                    {
                        Symbol = Symbol.Back;
                        Way = Ways.Right;
                    }
                    else if (Symbol == Symbol.Back)
                    {
                        Symbol = Symbol.Forward;
                        Way = Ways.Left;
                    }
                    else if (Symbol == Symbol.Accept)
                    {
                        if (AutoChangeColor)
                        {
                            SI.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        }
                        Symbol = Symbol.Cancel;
                        Way = Ways.Accept;
                    }
                    else if (Symbol == Symbol.Cancel)
                    {
                        if (AutoChangeColor)
                        {
                            SI.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                        }
                        Symbol = Symbol.Accept;
                        Way = Ways.Cancel;
                    }
                    else if (Symbol == Symbol.FullScreen)
                    {
                        Symbol = Symbol.BackToWindow;
                        Way = Ways.FullScreen;
                    }
                    else if (Symbol == Symbol.BackToWindow)
                    {
                        Symbol = Symbol.FullScreen;
                        Way = Ways.BackToWindow;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Symbol == Symbol.Forward)
                    {
                        Symbol = Symbol.Back;
                        Way = Ways.Left;
                    }
                    else if (Symbol == Symbol.Back)
                    {
                        Symbol = Symbol.Forward;
                        Way = Ways.Right;
                    }
                    else if (Symbol == Symbol.Accept)
                    {
                        if (AutoChangeColor)
                        {
                            SI.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        }
                        Symbol = Symbol.Cancel;
                        Way = Ways.Cancel;
                    }
                    else if (Symbol == Symbol.Cancel)
                    {
                        if (AutoChangeColor)
                        {
                            SI.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                        }
                        Symbol = Symbol.Accept;
                        Way = Ways.Accept;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public IconButton()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Symbol _symbol;
        public Symbol Symbol
        {
            get { return _symbol;}
            set
            {
                SI.Symbol = value;
                _symbol = value;
            }
        }

        private void BT_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(Cursor)
            {
                InitCursor();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="DosFab.App.CustomControl.IconButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:DosFab.App.CustomControl"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    MinHeight="30"
    MinWidth="30">
    <Button Name="BT" Padding="0" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="BT_Loaded">
        <SymbolIcon Name="SI"/>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

And now i use this button in another page and when i bind `Way` like this `<customcontrol:IconButton Symbol="FullScreen" Cursor="True" Way="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.Way, Mode=TwoWay}"/>` VisualStudio give me this error *TwoWay binding target 'Way' must be a dependency property* and i can't use the Click event too.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the error message indicate, you need to make your Way property as a [DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview#dependency-properties-and-windows-runtime-properties) in `IconButton` class. A dependency property is property that exists on a DependencyProperty identifier. A DependencyProperty identifier is usually a constant value to identify the property, it is typically public and read-only.

Add a define of Dependency property identifier of `Way` property like this:

IconButton.xaml.cs

```
……
public static readonly DependencyProperty WayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Way",typeof(Ways),typeof(IconButton),new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Then, you could use two-way binding and the click event can work.
If you have any other concerns, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I find how to use this DependencyProperty. You really help me one more time !